# AWS EC2 Default VPC access from CLI Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've created an AWS account for testing purposes on EC2 instances, so i've got access on the AWS EC2 console and started an instance then i've customise it to suit my needs then i created a snapshot (Private AMI).

Then I installed the CLI Tools to launch it with a command line, but my default VPC wasn't the same that the one on the AWS EC2 Console, so i can't access any of my instances or my personnal AMIs, i've looked for changing it but no way.

**EC2 Console from the web browser** : Default VPC : vpc-9bc325fe

**On the command prompt :**

$ ec2-describe-vpcs
VPC vpc-384db15d    available   172.31.0.0/16   dopt-667b6f04   default true

Any one have an idea how can i switch from vpcs or if there's another way to coordinate ?

Comment: There can only be 1 default VPC it is the same one irrespective of CLI/Console/API. Still not sure what exactly is your question.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer there's a default VPC for every region, so my CLI was pointing ( due to the EC2_URL global var ) on a different region than the one i'm using on the Amazon UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are using the same region on the CLI and the console, as VPCs are per-region, that may be the cause of the difference between CLI and web console.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i've got to change the EC2_URL var to the region of my VPC ( the one on which i've created the AMI ) and it works right now :)